# Accessing an encapsulated class slots within the encapsulating class method in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I have the following basic classes and methods:

```
        (defgeneric connect-edge (edge))

        (defclass Node ()
          ((forward-edges :initform nil)
           (backward-edges :initform nil)
           (value :initform 0.0)))

        (defclass Edge ()
          ((value :initform 0.0)
           (nodes :initform nil)))

        (defmethod connect-edge ((edge Edge))
        ;; does nothing important. Simplified to cause the problem
            (slot-value (car (slot-value edge 'nodes)) 'forward-edges))
```

I simplified the method enough to give me an error. Basically it doesn't do anything useful at this point, but it is enough to demonstrate the problem.

**Setup**:

The `Edge` class has `nodes` which is a list of `Node` objects. The `Node` class has lists of `Edge` objects.

**Intention:**

Read/ write the `forward-edges` and `backward-edges` in the `Node` objects encapsulated within an `Edge` object (the node list)

**Problem/Question:**

This "works" by returning `nil` as expected:

```
(defparameter *edge* (make-instance 'Edge))
(setf (slot-value *edge* 'nodes) (list (make-instance 'Node) (make-instance 'Node)))
(connect-edge *edge*)
```

This code gives me the error below, **Why**?

```
(connect-edge (make-instance 'Edge))

There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION (SB-PCL::SLOT-ACCESSOR :GLOBAL
                               COMMON-LISP-USER::FORWARD-EDGES
                               SB-PCL::READER) (1)>
when called with arguments
  (NIL).
```

Also, if I do this, I get the error below, which I think I understand why: No generic function defined which takes nil:

```
(connect-edge nil)

There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::CONNECT-EDGE (1)>
when called with arguments
  (NIL).
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

**Why am I doing all this?**

I have the following code which causes (perhaps for different reason) similar error:

```
(defun make-classic (net)
  (loop
     for this-layer in net
     for next-layer in (cdr net)
     do
       (loop
      for this-node in this-layer
      do
        (loop
           for next-node in next-layer
           do
         (let ((edge (make-instance 'Edge)))
           (setf (slot-value edge 'nodes) '(this-node next-node))
           (format t "Type of edge is ~a~%" (type-of edge))
           ;; Error is here
           (connect-edge edge))))))
```

I wasn't sure if the error is due to passing a scoped variable, so I ended up trying to pass a `(make-instance 'Edge)` to cause the error.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367496/common-lisp-passing-an-object-to-a-method

Comment: It’s largely unrelated but it’s generally considered bad form to use `slot-value` outside of low level methods (just like using public fields is bad form in Java). Instead you can use the `:reader` or `:accessor` arguments during `defclass`. It’s also usually unidiomatic to use mixed case for symbols unless the reader is set to be case sensitive (some people use typographical conventions like `<class>` for class names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need:

> when called with arguments (NIL).

```
(slot-value (make-instance 'Edge) 'nodes)
```

is `nil`, so

```
 (slot-value (car (slot-value edge 'nodes)) 'forward-edges))
```

fails.

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that (slot-value nil 'forward-edges) gives different error (the slot
FORWARD-EDGES is missing from the object NIL.) .

Comment: Thanks. I see. I changed '(this-node next-node) to (list this-node next-node), which was the issue. Your answer (and comment) explained what was the issue which helped me find it.